# How to make my taxonomy URL work?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, urls

I register my taxonomy ( **Writer** ) with this code :

```
function writer() {

  $labels = array(
    'name'                       => 'writer',
    'singular_name'              => 'writer',
    'menu_name'                  => 'writers',
    'all_items'                  => 'show all',
    'parent_item'                => 'parent',
    'parent_item_colon'          => 'parent:',
    'new_item_name'              => 'add new writer',
    'add_new_item'               => 'add',
    'edit_item'                  => 'edit',
    'update_item'                => 'update',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'separate with comma',
    'search_items'               => 'search',
    'add_or_remove_items'        => 'add/remove',
    'choose_from_most_used'      => 'most used',
    'not_found'                  => 'not found',
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'rewrite'                    => array('slug' => 'writer'),
  );
  register_taxonomy( 'writer', array( 'books_type' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'writer', 0 );
```

and i made a file with `taxonomy-writer.php` name in my theme directory. And i can access my taxonomies with URLs like this :

```
http://localhost/test/writer/ala-alam-falaki
```

But the problem is, when i try this URL :

```
http://localhost/test/writer/
```

I get 404, why can't i access this page ? what is the problem ?

Comment: That page does not exist. It is exactly the same as visiting `http://example.com/category/`. These pages are set by default to 404

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanks, but is there any way to make this page work ? _( other than make a page in wordpress admin area. )_

Comment: AFAIK, no unfortunately